# Pass PHP Date variable to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php date created with the code:

```
$date = date("d-m-Y");
```

I can echo this date out with:

```
echo $date;
```

and that works fine. But I want to pass this to a javascript function onClick of a button on my page. So I have:

```
<input type="button" onClick="myFunction(<?php echo $date; ?>)" value="Today">
```

Pretty standard. But when I alert the function in javascript:

```
function myFunction(phpDate) {

    alert(phpDate);

}
```

it then gives me:

```
-2018
```

in an alert box.

**Full code**

For anyone wondering, here is my full code:

```
<?php

    $date = date(d-m-Y);
    echo $date;      // to test date is working (it is)

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction(phpDate) {

        alert(phpDate);
        document.getElementByID("dateField").valueAsDate = phpDate;

        // can someone please tell me if ^^^this^^^ line above is correct syntax wise. 
        // I'm particularly concerned with '.valueAsDate'.

    }

</script>

<html>
    <input type="date" id="dateField">
    <input type="button" onClick="myFunction(<?php echo $date; ?>)" value="Today">
</html>
```

BTW I do have `<!doctype html>` and `<head>` and `<body>` tags in there. So my page works.

Comment: The value of an [*HTML Date input*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format, not d-m-y. Note that the built–in ECMAScript parser will treat the date as UTC, so be careful of that (hence it's suggested to avoid the built–in parser and use your own simple parse function or a library).

Comment: @RobG. That helps but could you please provide some code to help me.

Comment: Your PHP date should be Y-m-d, and `<input type="date" id="dateField" value="<?php echo $date; ?>)">`. doctype, head and body tags are all optional, but nice to have.

Comment: @RobG Your Y-m-d works. I get the correct date being passed through. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually passing the date as `Number` (`2 - 1 - 2019` = `-2018` for example), not as a `String`. You will need to wrap the date value in single quotes

```
<input type="button" onClick="myFunction('<?php echo $date; ?>')" value="Today">
```

Comment: Will try this. Thank-you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been busy. But I can confirm that this works. Thanks a lot.